# Acronym for ACRONYM describing acronyms as being numerous and/or overwhelming?

Tags: acronyms

I'm interning in a large organisation, and acronyms are everywhere. On my first day, I felt overwhelmed by them and now that I'm coming to the end of the internship, I want to come up with an acronym for ACRONYM to describe my experience.

Something along the lines of "Acronyms cannot reliably orchestrate new blah blah" would be good. Can anyone help?

Comment: You are welcome to take this question to our chat, but it's not a good fit for the main site. It is too open-ended, subjective and argumentative. There is *no* correct answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Is there no respite from your undiluted zeal for closing questions? We're just having a bit of fun here: nothing 'argumentative' about it.

Comment: I have voted to reopen.

Comment: assholes commonly run off new yucky mediocrities

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I figured this question was also a bit of creative fun, but I guess the moderators aren't fans of fun.

Comment: This one certainly isn't.

Comment: Ambiguous combinations resisting obvious necessity you make sense (ACRONYMS).

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively state your opinion about acronyms by calling the first new one that comes up a [**YABA**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Yaba&defid=1663323):

> Yet Another Bloody Acronym

Commonly used is also **TLA** for *Three Letter Acronym*. It seems neutral, but someone mentioning there are too many TLAs in a text gets his negative message through. :)

Comment: I like it, but this is also a professional presentation, so I don't want to come across as too negative. I was looking to state a fact about the amount of acronyms floating around, rather than give my opinion that they're a bad thing.

Comment: TLA is a great suggestion (FWIW note too it often means "three letter agency" when talking about the oppressive USA gov't of the 20th century.)

Answer (score 1):

All I can find is [this](http://www.abbreviations.com/ACRONYM):

> A Coded Rendition Of Names Yielding Meaning

Nothing to do with numerous though

Maybe

> Acronyms Create Really Obnoxious (and) Numerous Yearlong Mix-ups.

Answer (score 1):

How about this take on ZenLogic's answer:

> Abundant Confusing Renditions Of Names Yielding Meaning

or

> (An) abundance (of) Confusing Renditions Of Names Yielding Meaning

It highlights the number of them as well as the fact you haven't a clue what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

"A Compressed Representation Of Nouns You'd Misspell"

Answer (score 0):

Acronyms confuse rookies, old-timers, newbies -- yet multiply.

Aberrant capitals rampage over networks, yielding mystification.

Adopting contractions, reductive overlords nominate your minutiae.